# How string columns are compared by SQL engine?

Tags: mysql

Lets assume , I have below table and the output has given below .

In on condition "t1.name < t2.name" 2 string columns are compared , how the string column compared in background by SQL engine.

```
Team
    ----
    India
    Pakistan
    Srilanka
    Australia


    Output :
    ----
    India VS Pakistan
    India VS Srilanka
    India VS Australia
    Pakistan VS Srilanka
    Pakistan VS Australia
    Srilanka VS Australia
```

Query :

```
with teams as (
      select 'India' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Pakistan' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Srilanka' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Australia' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
     )
select t1.team as team1, team2.team team2
from teams t1 join
     teams t2
     on t1.name < t2.name;
```

Comment: By *what* data engine? You've tagged four *very* different RDBMS here.

Comment: Don't spam DBMS tags. You'll attract people who are most likely unable to help you. Update your post with only one DBMS tag.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared according to their collation, or a collation specified in the expression.

A collation defines whether any given pair of characters are equal, or if not equal, which one is greater.

When MySQL compares strings, it compares the characters in the two strings one character at a time. It uses the collation to determine if the characters are equal. For example in the default collation, `'e'` and `'é'` are equal.

```
mysql> select 'e' = 'é';
+------------+
| 'e' = 'é'  |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

If the characters are equal, it moves on to the next character in each string, again comparing them according to the collation. It keeps going until it finds characters that are not equal. The collation also tells which one is less than the other.

You can use a variety of national collations.

You can override the string's natural collation by specifying one in the expression.

If you use a binary collation, MySQL optimizes by using a single `memcmp()` call to compare the string of byte values. No collation is used, any difference in the byte values makes the characters unequal.

```
mysql> select 'e' = 'é' collate utf8mb4_bin;
+--------------------------------+
| 'e' = 'é' collate utf8mb4_bin  |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+
```